# Finding the Depth-First Index of a Child Given the Parent's Depth First Index Index in Complete k-ary Tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

I have a complete k-ary tree with a depth of `d`. If I'm given a node's depth-first index, I'd like a closed-form formula for calculating both the nodes children's depth-first indexes along with a formula for calculating the node's depth.

It's possible I just haven't searched the correct terms, but I was only able to find the following blog post on the topic: https://research.swtch.com/treenum

Comment: what do you mean by depth-first index? 
Is it the node index of preorder, inorder or postorder traversal?